# How to add namespace element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem.

Element Response must be without namespaces (They are defined root element).

Input XSLT:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet
        xpath-default-namespace="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:h="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST"
        version="1.0"
        >

  <xsl:template match="h:Response[not(h:OrderViewProcessing)]">
    <Response xmlns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST">
      <OrderViewProcessing>
            <MarketingMessages>
                <MarketingMessage>
                    <Text>
                      Error text
                    </Text>
                </MarketingMessage>
            </MarketingMessages>
        </OrderViewProcessing>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Response>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
<Response    xmlns:h="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST"
             namespace="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST">

      <OrderViewProcessing>
         <MarketingMessages>
            <MarketingMessage>
               <Text>
              Error Text
                    </Text>
            </MarketingMessage>
         </MarketingMessages>
      </OrderViewProcessing>

</Response>
```

I need like XML:

```
<Response>

      <OrderViewProcessing>
         <MarketingMessages>
            <MarketingMessage>
               <Text>
              Error Text
                    </Text>
            </MarketingMessage>
         </MarketingMessages>
      </OrderViewProcessing>

</Response>
```

If you remove xmlns = "http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST" in XSLT, then xmlns = "" in XML becomes empty.

**Update**

This problem solved in this way:

```
<xsl:template match="h:Response[not(h:OrderViewProcessing)]">
    <xsl:element name="Response" namespace="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST">
      <xsl:element name="OrderViewProcessing" namespace="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST">
            <xsl:element name="MarketingMessages" namespace="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST">
                <xsl:element name="MarketingMessage" namespace="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST">
                    <xsl:element name="Text" namespace="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST">
              Error text
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Probably, solution must be better.

Comment: That `apim` prefix isn't in your XSLT, so it must come from your input XML. We'll need to see the input XML to figure out where each namespace comes from and what context the given element is in.

Answer (score 1):

You're using xpath-default-namespace and version="1.0", which looks inconsistent, since this attribute is defined only in XSLT 2.0. You **always** need to tell us which version of XSLT you are using.

You're explicitly creating the Response element in namespace `"http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST"` though you say you want it to be in no namespace. Why are you doing this?

You say that your output has the attribute `namespace="http://www.iata.org/IATA/EDIST"` but there is nothing in your XSLT that could conceivably generate this attribute. I think this must have been from some experimental variation of your XSLT.

In general, if you need to declare namespaces in the stylesheet and don't want them copied into the output, you should specify `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"` on the xsl:stylesheet element. But I think there's a little bit more going on here that you haven't explained clearly.